# Comparison operator not working(Java Script)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, comparison-operators

I am trying to replace all the letters of a string by the next letter in the alphabet.

For example: a --> b or i --> j.

My program is ignoring the if statement that checks a letter against the alphabet array. When I try running the code it replaces all letters by "A", the last element in the alphabet array.

Although inefficent, I cannot find any errors with this algorithm. So why is the program ignoring the if statement?

```
function LetterChanges(str){ 
var alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","a"];
str = str.toLowerCase();
var ans = str.split("");

for(i = 0; i < ans.length; i ++)//Running through for each letter of the input string
{
    for(a = 0; a < 26; a++)//Checking each letter against the alphabet array
    {
        if(alphabet[a] == ans[i])
        {
          ans[i] = alphabet[a+1];
        }
    }
}
return ans;
}

LetterChanges("Argument goes here");
```

Comment: And pleeeeeease declare local variables, like `a` and `i` or eventually you'll run into really funny bugs.

Comment: @Thomas Just for clarification, are you saying that I should have `var a = 0` and `var i = 0` somewhere before my for loops?

Comment: And also use ` === ` while checking as it is a good practice as it also checks the data type of the two values you are comparing.However ,here it is not necessary.

Comment: a simple `var a,i;` somewhere (anywhere) inside the function would be sufficient, but as you need this variable only inside the loop, I'd got with `for(var i=0; ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it is not working, is because the `ans` array is modified, whilst you are still checking it.

In this loop:

```
for(a = 0; a < 26; a++)//Checking each letter against the alphabet array
{
    if(alphabet[a] == ans[i])
    {
      ans[i] = alphabet[a+1];
    }
}
```

If the `if` statement is found to be true, `ans[i]` will be updated, but then on the next loop of the iteration, it will likely be true again, as you are checking against the updated `ans[i]` variable.

As @xianshenglu suggested, you can fix this issue by adding a `break` to escape from the inner loop once a correct match is found.

```
for(a = 0; a < 26; a++) {
  if(alphabet[a] == ans[i]) {
    ans[i] = alphabet[a+1]
    // escape from the inner loop once a match has been found
    break
  }
}
```

---

For an alternative way to do this, you could do the following:

```
var result = str.toLowerCase().split('').map(ch => {
  var pos = alphabet.indexOf(ch)
  return pos >= 0 ? alphabet[pos + 1] : ch
}).join('')
```

---

And if you want to get rid of the `alphabet` array, you can use char codes. For example:

```
var result = str.toLowerCase().split('').map(ch => {
  var code = ch.charCodeAt(0)
  if(code < 96 || code > 122){ return ch }
  return String.fromCharCode((code - 96) % 26 + 97)
}).join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

you lost `break` when `if` executed

```js
function LetterChanges(str){ 
var alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","a"];
str = str.toLowerCase();
var ans = str.split("");

for(i = 0; i < ans.length; i ++)//Running through for each letter of the input string
{
    for(a = 0; a < 26; a++)//Checking each letter against the alphabet array
    {
        if(alphabet[a] == ans[i])
        {
          ans[i] = alphabet[a+1];
           break;
        }
    }
}
return ans;
}

console.log(LetterChanges("Argument goes here"));
```